# Cannot drop a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I want to drop a few tables in my postgresql database. I am able to drop a few tables but there are 3 tables which I am unable to drop.

I need to drop a few tables in my Postgres DB. I tried the following

Cannot read termcap database; using dumb terminal settings.

```
jiradb=> drop table "AO_3A3ECC_JIRACOMMENT_MAPPING";
DROP TABLE
jiradb=> drop table "AO_3A3ECC_REMOTE_IDCF";
DROP TABLE
jiradb=> drop table "AO_3A3ECC_JIRAPROJECT_MAPPING";
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for constraint 1152954
jiradb=>
```

I get this Cache lookup error. How do i fix this?

Comment: PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`)? Platform and OS version? Anything further in the PostgreSQL server error logs? Any recent changes?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.6
20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11), 64-bit

Comment: We didnot change anything in the database. But this DB is used by JIRA. We installed a plugin calles "Service Rocket Salesforce.com connector". The table that I mentioned above is used by this connector. I want to fix that connectorby uninstalling all its components. I am able to drop few tables related to it except 2.

Comment: If you're lucky something just modified the catalogs directly; try a database restart.

Comment: If that doesn't help try `REINDEX`ing the database ... but if you have to do that, then something's wrong, and I'd be making sure I was on the current patch release, checking my disks/memory, etc.

Comment: How do I restart DB? I have restarted psql using /etc/init.d/postgres restart.

Comment: When I try REINDEX for database, I get the following error. jiradb=# REINDEX DATABASE jiradb;
NOTICE:  table "pg_class" was reindexed
NOTICE:  table "pg_type" was reindexed
ERROR:  could not create unique index "pg_statistic_relid_att_index"
DETAIL:  Table contains duplicated values.

Comment: Right, so you've had index corruption that's permitted duplicate values to appear in a table that should have a unique index. The syscache errors as well make me seriously concerned about the state of your database. Read and act on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption - and also take a `pg_dump` of your database *now*