# What is preventing DROP TABLE from removing a Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, psql, drop-table

I have a postgres database named `aarons_db` in ubuntu linux. I'm trying to delete a table called `pnt` within `aarons_db`. To do this, I am using the following command:

```
DROP TABLE pnt
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to drop the table. My best guess is that there is some sort of admin privileges that I have not configured properly. The following shows the database, and commands used to try and drop the table.

What is preventing me from dropping the `pnt` table?

There is a similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82648/84875), although the user is running into a cache error, which is not happening in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer, originally a comment on the question by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)*</sub>

You need to end every SQL statement with `;`. You didn't do that and thus your statement was not executed at all. Run `DROP TABLE pnt;` instead. See e.g. here: [Understanding postgres prompts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66413/1822)